# How to config TypeScript to hide all global variables from window, but access window itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope

How to config TypeScript to hide all global variables from window, only access window itself?

Example:

This code works without any problems:

```
function foo(length: number): void {
  // Console result: A number from this scope.
  console.log(length);
}
```

but when I remove the parameter `length`. The linter is still satisfied. 
Because `length` is a global variable from `window`. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

```
function foo(): void {
  // Console result: A number from window. (not expected in this case)
  console.log(length);
}
```

Expected:

```
function foo(): void {
  // Console result: undefined (or my global variable if exist)
  // And in case the variable does not exist, the linter will cry as expected.
  console.log(length);
}
```

I want to hide the window scope in global access. But I still want access the window object itself if I call it explizit like:

```
function foo(): void {
  // This already works. But length itself without window as context should fail.
  console.log(window.length);
}
```

Is there a tsconfig or tslint option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-restricted-globals/ tslint version >= 5.13.0